# Convert Array into String Format using sqlite android

Tags: android, arraylist, android-sqlite

I am saving array list value into sq-lite database. I am getting the value into this format after the loop [1,2] before loop [[1,2]] but i want to get value in loop like:

```
1
2
```

What is the proper way to do this?

here is my code, This is where i am saving arraylist value into database

```
    public ArrayList<String> getpid (int id){
    sqLiteDatabase =this.getReadableDatabase();
    ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
    String sql="select p_id from cart where customer_id = '" + id + "' ";
    Cursor cursor=sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(sql,null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String idd = cursor.getString(0);
            String pid = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("p_id"));
            list.add(pid);
            System.out.println("===pid"+pid);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }return list;
```

and this code where i am trying to get value into string format one by one

```
enter code here  ArrayList<String> arrayList=mydatabase.getpid(idd);
    System.out.println("--outside"+arrayList);
    for(int i =0; i<arrayList.size(); i++){

        String value=arrayList.get(i).toString();
        System.out.println("---size"+value);

    }
```

Comment: I am unable to understand your question. You are not saving anything here to database. Could you post the logs of the sout's.

Comment: simply i want to get arraylist value from sqlite database

Comment: Could you post your logs? So that i can see the values of the variables.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

1st convert your array list to a string using .toString.
Then replace its ',' by ' '. then output will be like [1 2]. If you want to remove '[]' Symbols, replace '[' by "" and ']' by "".

```
ArrayListString.replace(',',' ') //Comma replace by space symbol. Also you can remove other symbols by using this method.
```

Comment: but i dont want output like this i want output using loop

Comment: I'm happy to hear your problem is solved. Its pleasure to help you. And if its solved your problem, mark this answer as the correct answer. Thanks!.